# Looping 3 divs continuously

Tags: jquery, loops, html

I`ve got 3 different contents of divs placed on the same position in css.

```
<div class="sidebanner_01">
abc
</div>

<div class="sidebanner_02">
def
</div>

<div class="sidebanner_03">
ghi
</div>
```

I need them to change continuously (fade between each other maybe?).

Sorry for a newbie question. jQuery can be used.

Comment: @Raminson Nothing to be exact, real newbie here and need to make this work asap.

Comment: So you want to have a slideshow, showing one `div` at a time?

Comment: Take a look at the Cycle plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: @Abraham Exactly! Thank you for simplifying that for me! :)

Comment: @Faust I`ve used that once, but not sure if it can be used for div elements. I don`t see any example of using div`s.

Comment: I would recommend the Cycle jQuery plugin that Faust suggested.

Comment: Sure, you can use Cycle with divs. They explain how on their site:  http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/div.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a ***very basic*** fiddle that should do what you want. Note that plugins are much better as they have much more functionality, but this should do it if you want a ***very basic*** system.

http://jsfiddle.net/r9ngh/2/

```
var slideShowDivs = ['.sidebanner_01', '.sidebanner_02', '.sidebanner_03'];
var currentID = 0;
var slideShowTimeout = 1000;
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 1; i < slideShowDivs.length; i++) $(slideShowDivs[i]).hide();
    setTimeout(slideShowChange, slideShowTimeout);
});
function slideShowChange() {
    var nextID = currentID + 1;
    if (nextID >= slideShowDivs.length) nextID = 0;
    $(slideShowDivs[currentID]).stop(true).fadeOut(400);
    $(slideShowDivs[nextID]).stop(true).fadeIn(400, function() {
        setTimeout(slideShowChange, slideShowTimeout);
    });
    currentID = nextID;
}​
```

Comment: The issue with this is the text fading in and it jumps to go to the top. Any way to do it smoother?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use jquery's fadeIn() and fadeOut() functions and a difrent timer function for timer functions you could use setTimeout() or doTimeout()

As for related links to this resources, all get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an example:

```
function slide(){

$('div[class^=sidebanner_]').each(function(i,e){

    var op = $(e).css('opacity') == 0 ? 1 : 0;   
    $(e).animate({'opacity': op}, 1000 * i);

});

}

setInterval(slide, 3000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Demo - smooth fade in and fade out transition : http://jsfiddle.net/gmefu/3/

Place the content inside div with class slider

```
 <div class="slider">abc</div>
 <div class="slider">def</div>
 <div class="slider">ghi</div>
```